# how to fix when chatbot hangs

Tags: python, android, artificial-intelligence, roblox

I am creating a chatbot based on The Talking NPC game in Roblox

it crashes after i type hello

error code

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in 
> start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
> File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
> exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  **main**.**dict**)
> File "", line 21, in 
> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

code

````
import random

print(" AI created by MThien \n")

sys = input(" [ System ]: My name is: ")

sys2 = 0
sys4 = 0

while True:
    user  = input(" [ " + str(sys) + " ]: ")
    
    sys1 = random.choice(["Hello!", "Hello there", "Hello " + str(sys), "Sup!", "Howdy!", "Wassup!"])
    sys2 = random.choice(["Wrong number, sorry.", "Apologize, my visitor is just having a mental breakdown."])
    sys3 = random.choice(["What?", "?", "Sorry?", "I don't understand", "I don't get it.", "Sry my English is bad.", "Sry my IQ is still low."])
    sys4 = random.choice(["...", "Stop it.", "You've already said hello to me several times.", "That's enough for greeting me."])

    if user == "hello":
        print(" [ AI ]: " + str(sys1))
        sys4 += 1
        if sys4 >= 5:
            print(" [ AI ]: "+ str(sys4)) 
    elif user == "/call":
        print(" [ Telephone ] : *dialing*")
        time.sleep(2)
        print(" [ Telephone ] : The number you're calling isn't registered.")
        time.sleep(1)
        print(" [ Telephone ] : *call ended*")
    elif user == "/call 911":
        print(" [ Telephone ] : *dialing*")
        time.sleep(2)
        print(" [ Telephone ] : 911, what's your emergency?")
        time.sleep(1)
        print(" [ AI ]: "+ str(sys1))
        time.sleep(1)
        print(" [ Telephone ] : *call ended*")
        sys2 += 1
        if sys2 == 3:
            time.sleep(3)
            print(" [ FBI ] : FBI, OPEN UP!")
            time.sleep(5)
            print(" [ System ]: You were kicked from this experience: You got arrested!")
            break
    else:
        print(" [ AI ]: " + str(sys3))```
````

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting your values when you likely don't intend to. Let's take a user input of `hello` for example. Prior to reaching this statement, you have two statements being

```
sys4 = 0
sys4 = random.choice(["...", "Stop it.", "You've already said hello to me several times.", "That's enough for greeting me."])
```

Once you hit that second statement, sys4 is now a string. You then get to `sys4 += 1`, where you are trying to add `1` to a string. Python does not support this, and it is obvious you were trying to add `1` to the integer version of `sys4` and not the string version. However, `sys4` no longer exists as an integer.

Properly name your variables and the problem should go away.

Also, the tags for `android` `artifical-intelligence`, and `roblox` are not relevant to this question.

Comment: Stack overflow caught tagging 1500 reputation